# uploadify jquery - giving wrong uploaded file type

Tags: php, uploadify

I'm using `$_FILES['Filedata']['type']` to get the file type, but it is giving `"application/octet-stream"` for every file I upload (i.e, .jpg / .pdf / .txt etc).

Can any one help me for this?

```
<form>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'auto' :true,
        'multi':true,
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
        'method'   : 'post',
        'formData':{'token':'xyz'},
         'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
            alert(data); }          
    });
});
</script>
```

## uploadify.php

```
$targetFolder = 'uploads'; 
$verifyToken =  $_POST['token'];
if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    echo $_FILES['Filedata']['type'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath =  $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/').'/'.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)) {
        echo 'Copied successfully';
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have input file which have name "`file_upload`", so try to change `$_FILES['Filedata']['type']` to `$_FILES['file_upload']['type']` because the first index should be the name of object.